# Cannot read property 'getRows' of undefined while call a procedure using node oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, node-oracledb

I created this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLE_COLUMN(tableName IN VARCHAR2, t_cursr OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN t_cursr FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = tableName;
END;
```

Which gets column names of a table which has it name pass as **tableName** then returns output to the **refcursor**.
Then i used oracledb to get result rows like this:

```
 const oracledb = require('oracledb');
 async function(proc, bind, ref, alter_script, acc){
        let connection;
        let row;
        let status = 'none';
        try{
            connection = await oracledb.getConnection(acc);
            
            if(alter_script === 'yes')
                await connection.execute(`alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true`);
            
            const result = await connection.execute(
                `BEGIN ${proc} END;`, // **"proc" is the procedure i mentioned**
                bind
            );
            if(ref === 'yes'){
                
                const resultSet = result.outBinds.cursor;
                row = await resultSet.getRows(369);// **I think the error comes from here**
                await resultSet.close();
            }

        } catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            status = 'occured';
        } finally{
            if(connection){
                try{
                    await connection.close();
                } catch(error){
                    console.error(error);
                    return status;
                } finally{
                    
                    if(ref === 'yes')
                        return row;
                    if(status === 'occured')
                        return 'failed!';
                    return 'done!'
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
};
```

After this, it will send the **row** to this function:

```
const execute_func = require('./execute_function/execute');
const jsonConfig = require('../jsonconfig/read_write');

module.exports = {
    callProc: async function(proc_name, bind_val, ref, alter_oracle, filePath, acc){
        let dataRows;
        try{
            //**This is where the row variable returned**
            dataRows = await execute_func.execute(proc_name, bind_val, ref, alter_oracle, acc);
        } catch (error){
            console.error(error);
        } finally{
          
            if(dataRows === 'failed!')
                return 'failed!';
           
            if(filePath)
                //**The i saved to json file**
                await jsonConfig.writeJson(dataRows, filePath);
            return 'done!';
        }
    }
};
```

Then when using nodejs to run the website which includes a feature operated by the above function i got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRows' of undefined
    at Object.execute (D:\Sync\school_documents\3nd_year\2ndTerm\anToan_baoMatDuLieuHTTT\doAn\adminApp\functions\execute_function\execute.js:21:39)
    at async Object.callProc (D:\Sync\school_documents\3nd_year\2ndTerm\anToan_baoMatDuLieuHTTT\doAn\adminApp\functions\callProc.js:9:24)
(node:10448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView.
```

I think the problem is from the way i write my procedure or the code but after long time researching i cannot fix it. Can everyone help me, please?. Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems that the error you mention isn't from the code you've posted.  I ran the code you've posted and it appeared to work.  It seems you have code elsewhere in your project (perhaps in your `execute.js` file?) that calls `fs.writeFile()` or `fs.writeFileSync()` (or similar) with invalid data for the second argument. Node v14 reports a similar error for `fs.writeFileSync("SomeFile", arg)` when `arg` isn't a string or any of the other types listed.  Could you edit the question to include `execute.js`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward my above function is the only function in my execute.js

Comment: @ i added more detail for you to see, here is my project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T1blGyU13H1NQewiExieWTI-V5g-wct_?usp=sharing, can i contact you through an chat app?

Comment: Firstly, please do not post an entire project and expect me (or anyone else) to look through and debug it all for you.  Nor expect to others to contact you over chat apps. Reduce the code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the error.  Does your code use `callProc` in one place or multiple places?  Do some of these calls work but others don't?  Find one call that doesn't work and add it to your question.  If you're struggling to figure which one it is that's causing problems, consider writing out `proc` with `console.log`.

Comment: Do some debugging.  Your "`BEGIN ${proc} END;`," call looks wrong. If it's creating the procedure, you should remove the BEGIN & END.  If it's calling the procedure you need to bind some values in the `execute()`.  Start by reviewing the node-oracledb examples https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples

Comment: @ChristopherJones: that block is calling the procedure, and the variables to bind are passed in the `bind` argument.  The code posted by the OP works: I've used it to list a table's columns.  The OP hasn't got an answer because they haven't been able to produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Still stuck on this one?  Take a logical approach.  If you can't call `getRows` on `undefined`, then `resultSet` must be undefined.  This means `result.outBinds` doesn't have a property named `cursor`.  Try writing `result.outBinds` to `console.log` to see what properties it actually has.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the definition of `t_cursr` in `GET_TABLE_COLUMN` to `t_cursr IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` or rewrite `GET_TABLE_COLUMN` as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLE_COLUMN(tableName IN VARCHAR2, t_cursr OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
  csr  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN csr FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = tableName;

  t_cursr := csr;
END GET_TABLE_COLUMN;
```

Comment: I think the problem is about the proc, i granted all privilege to USER_TAB_COLUMNS, i also try switch to ALL_TAB_COLUMNS but that didn,t work.